# Coupled Hover Events in AG-Charts

Tags: ag-charts-react, ag-charts

In Plotly they offer the option of coupling the popout labels of multiple data series on hover. The last two examples on this page demonstrate the functionality
https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/#coupled-hover-events

I am trying to reproduce the following
[example of vertical labels on line graph data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txCSr.png)

I have searched through the documentation for AG-Grid and do not see any possible way to replicate this behavior, but I figure I might as well ask to be certain.